Find Cells with Button in them
In my Excelsheet  I have a row (9) which includes drop-down buttons which can select things like sum etc. How can I check if a row contains these buttons using VBA?
I have tried "HasValidation" and "If ws.Rows(i).AutoFilter" but were not successful

Might that be the ListObject.TotalsRowRange?

That row is not an ordinary row. It is part of an Excel (structured) table. You probably don't want to know what you're asking but how to append or delete data in the table considering whether 'that row' is visible or not. Please share your true goal i.e. the code that is failing because of 'that row'.

As stated in the comment, your "row with drop down buttons" is not regular row, it's a totals row of a table. The drop down buttons have nothing to do with data validation, therefore your attempt using HasValidation fails.
You can switch on/off this row in the table design:

Now you can get information about the ranges occupied by a table using VBA. First thing is you need to know that a table in VBA is named ListObject, and you can access all tables of a worksheet using the ListObjects-collection. The following code assumes that you want to know the details of the first table of the first sheet, adapt to your needs.
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, table As ListObject
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
Set table = ws.ListObjects(1)

You can check the ranges of the object table. If a table has the totals row enabled, the property ShowTotals is set to True and you can get the address of it using the TotalsRowRange-property.
Debug.Print "Table Range: ", table.Range.Address 
Debug.Print "Header Row: ", table.HeaderRowRange.Address 
Debug.Print "Data Range: ", table.DataBodyRange.Address
If table.ShowTotals Then
    Debug.Print "Total Row: ", table.TotalsRowRange.Address
Else
    Debug.Print "Total Row: ", "(no total row)"
End If

Using the following table, the result is

Table Range:  $A$1:$H$9
Header Row:   $A$1:$H$1
Data Range:   $A$2:$H$8
Total Row:    $A$9:$H$9

So table.TotalsRowRange.Row would give you the desired row number (=9). However, in most cases you don't need that. You failed to explain what your ultimate goal is, but I assume you want to add a row above this total row, and that can easily be done with table.ListRows.Add which will create an empty row above the totals row.

The Range has Validation.Type property which is for a dropdown list is 3.
If the Range hasn't the property is an error.
For any validation of a cell
Sub valid()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("F1:F10")
On Error Resume Next
For Each cel In rng
    testval = cel.Validation.Type
    If Err = 0 Then
      Debug.Print "Cell ", cel.Address, " has Validation"
    Else
      Err = 0
    End If
Next cel
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub


or for dropdown
Sub valid()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("F1:F10")
On Error Resume Next
For Each cel In rng
    testval = cel.Validation.Type
    If testval = 3 Then
      Debug.Print "Cell ", cel.Address, " has Validation dropdown"
      testval = 0
    End If
Next cel
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub


